# AWS - having subdomains point to different applications - backend / react app / static landing page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, deployment

I'm currently developing a full-stack web application + mobile app. I've pushed my API backend (node.js express) to an AWS EC2 instance.

Now I'm looking to create the frontend with React. As well as a landing page which I think will be just plain HTML (or even WordPress if possible?) to get it running asap.

Questions are:

1. should I upload all 3 to the same instance? if so how?
2. can I point my domain in a way where mydomain.com - serves the landing page, api.mydomain.com serves the backend for requests, and app.mydomain.com serves the react app.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is entirely upto you here, if this is a personal project or one with a tight budget then yes you can put all applications onto the same server.

If you have a HTML only application then you could deploy that specific application to [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) with a [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) distribution in front to provide CDN functionality.

If you do run the applications on your server then you will need to ensure that the web server can resolve each set application individually through hostname for example Nginx uses `server_name` to define the web domain name for that vhost.

I would suggest if you're running all on the same box run each node application on a seperate port, then use Nginx as a proxy based on the domain name. More information on how to set this up is available [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Finally add DNS records to target the host IP (or CNAME if you use CloudFront).

Comment: Hi Chris, and thanks for the quick response.
If I'm getting this right.
I can upload each application (ai the backend and the frontend) on a different port of the same instance and then point a subdomain to the specific ip of the port?
Thanks

Comment: You would have the same IP address, internally you would run your NodeJS apps on a different port, then run Nginx on the same server to proxy your request to the port based on hostname. The browser would still interact on port 80/443 :)

Comment: Got it, brilliant. Thanks!